# How to match everything but a regular expression with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

given the following results using sed:

```
~ echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed 's/\ *+[a-zA-Z0-9\{._\-\:\-}]*\ */ /g'
drive kids to the Foo Bar -10:00
~ echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed 's/\ *+[a-zA-Z0-9\{._\-\}]*\ */ /g'
drive kids to the Foo Bar :00-10:00
~ echo pick suzieq up from +10:30-11:00 kung foobar practice | sed 's/\ *+[a-zA-Z0-9\{._\-\}]*\ */ /g'
pick suzieq up from :30-11:00 kung foobar practice
~ echo +11:15-12 pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar | sed 's/\ *+[a-zA-Z0-9\{._\-\}]*\ */ /g'
 :15-12 pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar
```

What I want is:

```
~ echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed 'some regular expression'
drive kids to the Foo Bar 
~ echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed 'some regular expression'
drive kids to the Foo Bar 
~ echo pick suzieq up from +10:30-11:00 kung foobar practice | sed 'some regular expression'
pick suzieq up from kung foobar practice
~ echo +11:15-12 pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar | sed 'some regular expression'
 pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar
```

As a side-note:
I have [a regular expression](http://rubular.com/r/aVGYPBofE4) that can select everything I want after the `+` symbol, but how would I translate what I've done in rubular to sed so that sed will: "select everything except my regular expression"? Thanks for your help :)

Edit:

```
~/sandbox/sed-practice echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed 's/([+][^[:space:]]+)?./\1/g'
sed: 1: "s/([+][^[:space:]]+)?./ ...": \1 not defined in the RE

~/sandbox/sed-practice echo drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00 | sed -r 's/([+][^[:space:]]+)?./\1/g'
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

Comment: Try `'s/([+][^[:space:]]+)?./\1/g'`

Comment: You need to pass `-r` option to sed. `sed -r 's/([+][^[:space:]]+)?./\1/g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see new edit

Comment: What is the environment? Try `-E`  if `-r` doesn't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using `zsh` is this what you mean by asking what the environment is? Also the `-E` option and your re successfully matches my rubular re but I'm trying to select everything except my re

Comment: I thought you were going to remove all but what the rubular regex matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for the mixup - I want to "select everything **except** what the regex matches"

Comment: Do you want to remove all the text not matching with your regex?

Comment: @anubhava yes that's what I'm going for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
# original input
cat file
drive kids to the Foo Bar +09:00-10:00
pick suzieq up from +10:30-11:00 kung foobar practice
+11:15-12 pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar

# sed command
sed 's/\(.*\)+[^[:space:]]*[[:blank:]]*/\1/g' file

drive kids to the Foo Bar
pick suzieq up from kung foobar practice
pick kids and new friends up from Foo Bar
```

- `[[:blank:]]` matches space or tab
- `[[:space:]]` matches space or tab or newline

Answer (score 1):

### Reversing the restriction with !

Sometimes you need to perform an action on every line except those that match a regular expression, or those outside of a range of addresses. The "!" character, which often means not in UNIX utilities, inverts the address restriction. You remember that

```
sed -n '/match/ p'
```

acts like the grep command. The "-v" option to grep prints all lines that don't contain the pattern. Sed can do this with

```
sed -n '/match/ !p'
```

Found the answer [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-32)